# How can I create a static reserved public IP address for my Azure VM?

Tags: ip, virtual-machine

I've created a Windows 2012 VM in Microsoft Azure using the Resource Manager.  In order to point the DNS of my site to this VM, I need to create a reserved IP address.  I'm running the following commands in Azure Powershell:

New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName MyReservedPublicIP –Location “WestUS”

But I get this error:

New-AzureReservedIP : BadRequest: The location constraint is not valid
OperationID : '90cc8e815938695ca2fcfd6bba0cc04d'
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName MyReservedPublicIP –Location “West US”
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureReservedIP], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.NewAzureReservedIPCmdlet

What am I missing?

Comment: I've tried "West US" and get the same result.

Comment: Ok so I've created a FQDN for my VM and the used a C name record to point to that domain and it seems to be working.  Is this all I need?